# How can I add a count property to objects with similar id in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of multiple objects, and based on the quantity, I managed to multiply the objects with similar id based on the quantity to make a carousel of products for a picking app:

I can´t figure out how to do it, maybe run a for loop. I'm using reduce to flatten the array.

```
const flattenedOrderProducts = await orderProductsArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
                    return [
                        ...acc,
                        ...Array.from({ length: item.quantity }, () => ({...item})),
                    ]
                }, [])

[
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 4040,
    "name": "Soap",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 4040,
    "name": "Soap",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 7313,
    "name": "Olive Oil",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 5670,
    "name": "Tomato 1kg",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 5670,
    "name": "Tomato 1kg",
    "quantity": 2
  }
```

What I'm looking to get is a counter --, for the picker to view how many got left to pickup.

```
[
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 4040,
    "name": "Soap",
    "quantity": 2,
    "itemsLeft": 2
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 4040,
    "name": "Soap",
    "quantity": 2,
    "itemsLeft": 1
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 7313,
    "name": "Olive Oil",
    "quantity": 1,
    "itemsLeft": 1
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 5670,
    "name": "Tomato 1kg",
    "quantity": 3,
    "itemsLeft": 3
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 5670,
    "name": "Tomato 1kg",
    "quantity": 3,
    "itemsLeft": 2
  },
  {
    "orderid": "28318",
    "id": 5670,
    "name": "Tomato 1kg",
    "quantity": 3,
    "itemsLeft": 1
  }
```

Comment: The map function you pass as the second argument to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes as its arguments the element and the index, the latter of which seems like it would be helpful in producing the `itemsLeft` property on `item`.

Comment: I know it has something to do with that Array.from, but it's the logic I don't get. Thanks tho!

Comment: What is the ```orderProductsArr```?

Comment: It's the same array of objects but without repeating the item object by the quantity. You can see that there are 2 Soap objects, in orderProductsArr there is only 1 Soap object with quantity: 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Heretic Monkey suggested you can indeed use the second argument in the array.from method. As such with very minimal adjustment to your example you get the following code, what (I believe) does exactly what you want.

```js
const flattenedOrderProducts = await orderProductsArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
                    return [
                        ...acc,
                        ...Array.from({ length: item.quantity }, (_, i) => ({...item, itemsLeft: i + 1})),
                    ]
                }, [])
```

Might I suggest some alterations. First do you really need the await? reduce is a synchronous function. Second by using the spread operator to fill the array you essentially copy the whole content of the array to a new array and return that. I would suggest implementing your function as something like

```js
const flattenedOrderProducts = orderProductsArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  for (let itemsLeft = 1; itemsLeft <= item.quantity; itemsLeft ++) {
    acc.push({ ...item, itemsLeft });
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
```

Comment: Oh nice suggestion, I tried it and it worked really smoothly. Thank you!!